# Swagger UI with multiple services

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-ui

Is there a way to "aggregate" (or at least link to) multiple Swagger APIs to display on a single UI?

Say I have two services, Foo and Bar, what I want to do is make a third service, Baz, that provides the metadata for Foo and Bar. **Foo, Bar, and Baz would be on different hosts**, which is why I'm not sure if this is possible.

---

One solution is to use the idea of service discovery (maybe not the correct term in this context) and have Baz serve links to Foo and Bar when a GET is performed.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: baz
Accept: application/json
...
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
...

{
    "services": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "link": "http://foo"
        },
        {
            "name": "bar",
            "link": "http://bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is how I'd approach this normally, but I'm wondering if there's a way to have the Swagger UI on Baz show the UI for both Foo and Bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I ended up doing was in the `index.html` file replacing the text box at the top of the page with a drop down list with links to various servers hosting the `swagger.json` files.

```
<div id='header'>
  <div class="swagger-ui-wrap">
    <a id="logo" href="http://swagger.io">swagger</a>
    <form id='api_selector'>

      <!-- Start of my changes -->

      <div class='input'>
        <select placeholder="http://example.com/api" id="input_baseUrl" name="baseUrl" type="text">
          <option value="http://foo/swagger.json">Foo</option>
          <option value="http://bar/swagger.json">Bar</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <!-- End of my changes -->

      <div class='input'><input placeholder="api_key" id="input_apiKey" name="apiKey" type="text"/></div>
      <div class='input'><a id="explore" href="#" data-sw-translate>Explore</a></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

A JavaScript script could be written to talk to your Eureka instance (or something similar) to get a url for each service and the dropdown list could be updated automatically. I'm no JavaScript or HTML expert so I don't know how to do this, but I am mentioning it because it's a possibility. This would be more useful so you don't need to update this file each time a new service is added.